# Generate JSON body from RAML file

Tags: json, raml, ready-api

I am testing REST APIs with Ready! API tool and the documentation that I have received is the raml files with the REST APIs definitions.

The RAML plugin of Ready! API works fine but the raml files don't include any example of the JSON bodies. There are many parameters/structures that compose these bodies, so, creating/generating these bodies is very tedious.

My question is: Is there any tool/way/definition/etc that can generate these bodies automatically or easier/faster?

The raml files are generated with raml maven plugin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you use Atom editor with api-workbench plugin you can you use API Console to gerate a HTML your RAML especification and the API Console will include the examples for you.

Comment: Im using Atom and Im trying to generate an API request with API console (workbench), but there is an error: Uncaught TypeError: e.examples is not a function. There are no examples included in raml file neither schema references. Any idea?

Comment: TypeError: e.examples is not a function
    at /*/.atom/packages/api-workbench/main.js:6:6272
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at e.render (/*/.atom/packages/api-workbench/main.js:6:6220)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (/*/.atom/packages/api-workbench/node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:789:34)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (/*/.atom/packages/api-workbench/node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:816:14)